# How to create HtmlTag from String

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I am using [HTMLTags](https://github.com/HtmlTags/htmltags/) library to write some MVC Html Helper classes. However I do not want to write everything from scratch and want to leverage existing MVC Html extension Helper methods for some code. The problem is I cannot figure out how to parse MVCHtmlString or String to HTMLTag.

I stumbled upon on an old [article](http://amoerie.com/2013/08/31/htmltag-its-the-new-tagbuilder/) which does mention HTMLTags library does it using Html Agility Pack but I cannot find this method in the new version.

Can someone assist me as to how I can parse string and convert it to HtmlTag class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating my own Extension Method to convert MvcHtmlString to HtmlTag.

```
public static HtmlTag ToHtmlTag(this MvcHtmlString html)
    {
        HtmlTag htmlTag = null;
        var doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(html.ToHtmlString());
        var tag = doc.DocumentNode.FirstChild;

        if (tag != null)
        {
            htmlTag = new HtmlTag(tag.Name);
            foreach (var attribute in tag.Attributes)
            {
                htmlTag.Attr(attribute.Name, attribute.Value);
            }
        }

        return htmlTag;
    }
```

I was hoping the HtmlTags library will contain some method to parse strings but as it does not this is probably the second best way in my opinion.

Now I can simple call this extension method like

```
var tag = html.TextBoxFor(expression, (String) null).ToHtmlTag();
```